# R: failed to make clusters by using dbscan (fpc)

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have a data.frame with 1000 obs. with 2 variables with a following descriptive summary;

```
      var1             var2       
 Min.   :   0.0   Min.   :   0.0  
 1st Qu.: 837.8   1st Qu.: 651.5  
 Median :1465.0   Media  : 819.5  
 Mean   :1421.6   Mean   : 832.6  
 3rd Qu.:1888.2   3rd Qu.: 990.0  
 Max.   :3799.0   Max.   :2271
```

and a scatter of plot, https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnffqoavoyaw8ms/Rplot04.png?dl=0

I have been trying to generate potential clusters by using dbscan (fpc) but have not been able to generate any clusters at all even though I have experimented with different values of eps(0.5 to 5) and minPts(5 to 20).

I would very much appreciate if anybody could suggest a starting point of eps and minPts to produce at least 2 clusters based on this data.frame.

Comment: What does "dbscan (fpc)" mean? Are you calling a function called `dbscan` on a data frame called `fpc`? No, you mean the `dbscan` function in the package `fpc`. Now show us your code and your output and how you think it is wrong.

Comment: @spacedman there is a R package `fpc` which contains a horribly slow and limited implementation of DBSCAN.

Answer (score 0):

Given the value range, eps=5 may be too low.

Have you tried the heuristic of choosing eps proposed in the DBSCAN paper?

But judging from your plot, **there is only one density-based cluster**. Probably GMM will work better for that data set. Maybe OPTICS and mean-shift will work, too. But DBSCAN will be hard to separate the two clusters (and you mustn't overfit the paramters)